# Password fa-eye is not toggled in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react js: When I press the button, the input works, it shows and hides password, but the icon in the button does not change!

Here is the state:

```
const [passwordType, setPasswordType] = useState(true);
```

Here is my button:

```
<Button className="btn" onClick={togglePasswordType} style={{ color: "lightgray" }}>
     <i className={!passwordType ? 'fas fa-eye-slash' : 'fas fa-eye'}></i>
</Button>
```

Here is my togglePasswordType:

```
const togglePasswordType = () => {
    setPasswordType(!passwordType)
}
```

Comment: Toggles the class fine for me, though you may as well pass a callback to setState `setPasswordType(passwordType => !passwordType);` [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-kirch-8nwuik?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

const RenderSwitchEye = useCallback (() => {
return (<i className={passwordType ? "fa fa-eye" : "fa fa-eye-slash" } aria-hidden="true">);
}, [passwordType]);

<Button className="btn" onClick={togglePasswordType} style={{ color: "lightgray" }}>

{So I called the function as a component within the button tag}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain your code and use proper formatting. Just sending code, especially with improper formatting, is very hard for beginners (and even professionals) to learn from. Read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Please mark this answer as worked with the check if it worked.